# Is (a+b)* and (ab)* same in finite automata?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions

Regular language of (a+b)* and (ab)* are: 
(a+b)* = { ε, a, b, aa , ab , bb , ba, aaa, ...}
(ab)* =   { ε, a, b, aa, ab, ba, bb, aaa, ... } 

I am new to Finite automata and this simple notion is confusing me!
I didn't find (a+b)* = (ab)* in rules of regular expressions.

Comment: No. $(ab)^*$ does not contains $aa$ (it only contains $\varepsilon, ab, abab, ababab,...$), whereas $(a+b)^*$ does.

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. Can you provide a reference for the two languages presented? (The second *might* have been denoted *[ab]\**.)

Comment: Simpler, $(ab)^*$ does not contain $a$.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expressions $(a+b)^*$ and $(ab)^*$ represent languages according to the semantics of regular expressions. Formally, the language $L[r]$ corresponding to a regular expression $r$ is defined as follows:

- $L[\emptyset] = \emptyset$.
- $L[\epsilon] = \epsilon$.
- $L[\sigma] = \sigma$ for $\sigma \in \Sigma$.
- $L[r_1+r_2] = L[r_1] \cup L[r_2]$.
- $L[r_1r_2] = L[r_1] L[r_2]$, where $L_1 L_2 = \{ w_1w_2 : w_1 \in L_1, w_2 \in L_2 \}$.
- $L[r^*] = L[r]^*$, where $L^* = \bigcup_{n \geq 0} L^n$, and $L^n$ is defined recursively by $L^0 = \{\epsilon\}$ and $L^{n+1} = L^n L$.

Two languages over the same alphabet are equal if they are equal as sets, that is, if they contain the same words. In your case, you haven't specified the underlying alphabet $\Sigma$, so I'm assuming that $\Sigma = \{a,b\}$.

Now that you have all the definitions, you can check for yourself whether $L[(a+b)^*]$ equals $L[(ab)^*]$.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not equal but (a+b)* and (a*b*)* are equal.

Comment: Are you sure about what you wrote ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust Some of the \*'s in the answer were interpreted as the emphasis notation in markdown. I've edited it to what seems to be the intention.

Answer (score 0):

No, $(ab)^*=\{\epsilon,ab,abab,abababa\cdots\}$. The length is always even.